# select data from a window of specific value

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to find a window for value based on values of a column. That particular value should be within a particular distance to its before and after values. For example, if there is a value 6, and is within a distance of 4 from its preceding and succeeding value, then I want to select values from this window of values from another column. For example,

```
word = c("A", "B", "c", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K");
pos = c("2", "6", "10", "16", "22", "31", "44", "51", "62", "72", "75");
val = c("2.34", "6.32", "1.34", "2.45", "2.34", "3.56", "3.7", "3.12", "2.22", "2.34", "4.51");
```

dat = data.frame(word, pos, val)

In the above data frame, the B has a value 6 and its corresponding 'val' is 6.32. I want to select the window for 6 which is +/- 4 on both sides, so the window should be  from 2 - 10 (column-pos). Based on this window, I want to select the minimum value of column 'val', so it will be 1.34.

Subsequently, for the value 10 (word-c), the window will be from 6 - 16 so the corresponding window values in column 'val' are 6.32, 1.34, 2.45, among them  the minimum value is 1.34.

I want to do this for all the values in pos column with +/- of 4 difference to their before and after value to generate a window for all values and select minimum 'val' values from that window of column 'val'. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What technology and code are you using? How is this a question about coding?

Comment: May be my question is not clear. I want to find a window of any rows either side of val less than a specific threshold, and then create a new data.table containing information regarding a specific character of these rows.

Comment: This is a website for help with **coding**.